# FIX engine for very low latency

Tags: market-data, market-making, fix, latency

We are building a new system where latency is key.
Either commercial or opensource, our goal is to have an easy to implement fix engine where low latency is key.

Comment: http://chronicle.software/products/transfix/

Comment: what is the question? :)

Comment: @LazyCat: I think it is 'where can I get a FIX engine that is cheap, fast and good?'.

Comment: No. It is what the best fix engines out there. Either commercial or open source

Answer (score 0):

For Forex,swaps,NDFs, most LPs supports >10ms execution time .with default quick-fix we could achieve <170ms latency for whole chain of processes of our application(from sending message to execution on server-side). So basically it depends on your application, how it should work & who's your LP & what latency range is your aim.

You can try with Onix instead of Quick-fix, but there won't be much upgrade in that regard.Performance & latency depends on a whole lot of other things.